# Solve pair of recurrence relations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

[Corrected equations and added simple example]

Can you solve a system of (loosely) coupled recurrence relations like this in *Mathematica* somehow?

```
{A[k] ==1+((n-k-2)/n) A[k+1] +(2/n) B[k+1] + (k/n) (A[0]), 
 B[k]==1+((n-k-1)/n) B[k+1] + (k/n) A[0]}
```

We want to solve it for $A[0]$ as a closed form function of $n$.

$A[k]$ is defined for $0 \leq k \leq n-2$ and $B[k]$ is defined for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$.

Version 8 doesn't do anything useful but I suspect I am not asking it in the right way.

As a simple example, if you set $n=3$ then you get four simulataneous equations.

```
A[0] == 1 + (2/3)*B[1] + (1/3)*A[1]
B[1] == 1 + (1/3)*A[0] + (1/3)*B[2]
B[2] == 1 + (2/3)*A[0]
A[1] == 1 + (2/3)*B[2] + (1/3)*A[0]
```

Solving for $A[0]$ gives you $33/5$ I believe.  To start things off, how do you get *Mathematica* to do this?

**Update.** If you just take the second recurrence alone.

```
B[k]==1+((n-k-1)/n) B[k+1] + (k/n) A[0]
```

How can you get *Mathematica* to give a sensible solution for $B[k]$ in terms of $n$ and $A[0]$? It seems Rsolve ought to be able to do this.  I even tried

```
RSolve[{B[k] == 1 + ((n - k - 1)/n) B[k + 1] + ((k)/n) (A[0]), 
  B[n - 1] == k A[0]/n}, B[k], k]
```

which should be identical. However this now gives an empty solution with the following warning.

```
RSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.
```

I would like to tell *Mathematica* to only try to solve it for the defined range of $k$. Is that possible?

Comment: If replace `A[0]` with constant and solve first for `B[k]` then solve for `A[k]` and replace `B[k]` with previous solution it works.

Comment: Please note that the second one isn't really "coupled" with the first but for a constant term `A[0]`. So `RSolve[B[k]==1+((n-k-2)/n) B[k+1]+((k+1)/n) (k+A[0]),B[k],k]` is able to cope with it.

Comment: I get a horrible expression from RSolve[B[k]==1+((n-k-2)/n) B[k+1]+((k+1)/n) (k+A[0]),B[k],k] in terms of Gamma, DifferenceRoot, some Function and Pochhammer. Is there some way to extract the leading terms?

Comment: @lip1 If by "extract the leading terms" you mean generate the first few terms in the sequence, RecurrenceTable is what you are looking for. Unless you can set the value of `n` though, you get very long expressions.

Comment: @belisarius I updated the question to fix some problems and clarify the ranges we are interested in.

Comment: @lip1 The new details make much more sense, but I don't see necessarily why `A[0]==6`. When I let A[0]=6, I get that it is defined on the range you specify, but I get the same results when `A[0]` is any integer.

Comment: Where does the number 33/5 come from?

Comment: @user141603 If you set n =3 then you get four simultaneous equations. eq1 := A[0] = 1+(2/3)*B[1]+(1/3)*A[1] , eq2 := B[1] = 1 +(1/3)*A[0] + (1/3)*B[2] , eq3 := B[2] = 1  + (2/3)*A[0] and eq4 := A[1] = 1 + (2/3)*B[2] + (1/3)*A[0] . Solve for A[0].

Comment: @lip1, have you had any progress on this?

Comment: The sequence of $A[0]$ for $n=2, 3, \ldots$ looks awful.  Here are the first few values: $4,\frac{33}{5},\frac{180}{19},\frac{4895}{389},\frac{3324}{209},\frac{1516053}{78077},\frac{2057464}{89035},\frac{89344035}{3313213},\frac{34098720}{1100657}$, $\frac{651528436361}{18539106101},\frac{1023370836}{25941989},\frac{748806039176247}{17061288862565},\frac{3970025895220}{81923134171},\frac{190746410563815}{3588341852791},\ldots$. It's not simple.  `FindSequenceFunction`, fwiw, fails to find any formula for these, for their numerators, or for their denominators.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but this solves it the same way you did. It generates all the equations and then solves them. If you only want $A_0$, use `Sol[n][[1,1]]`.

```
Sol[n_] := 
Solve[Take[
Flatten[Table[{Subscript[B, k] == 
   1 + ((n - k - 1) Subscript[B, k + 1])/n + (k Subscript[A, 0])/
    n, Subscript[A, k] == 
   1 + ((n - k - 2) Subscript[A, k + 1])/n + (
    2 Subscript[B, k + 1])/n + (k Subscript[A, 0])/n}, {k, 0, 
  n - 1}]], {2, -2}]]
```

Edit:

Here's a graph of the first 80 values:

[image: Graph of A_0]

And the first set of differences:

[image: Differences between consecutive A_0s]

That looks somewhere between $\sqrt{x}$ and $\log{x}$.

Comment: Thanks. What I am looking for is a solution as a function of $n$. I just gave an example to make sure it was clear what was going on. I was hoping Rsolve might be able to do something useful.

Comment: @lip1 This is a function of n in the Mathematica sense. Do you mean a mathematical function, like a closed form expression?

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for.

Comment: I've tried fitting some models to it and I have gotten very close, but I haven't found a closed form function.

Comment: user141063 Thanks! Shouldn't Rsolve be able to solve it explicitly?

Comment: I'm not sure about "should" but it doesn't seem able to. Mathematica 7 actually gives a closed form expression for the recurrence relation that only involves B[k], but it evaluates to Indeterminate for every value I've tried.