# How do I use RSolve to solve a system of recurrence relations?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I am trying to solve a system of recurrence relations as follows.

```
RSolve[{a[p] == 1 + (2/n) b[p - 1] + ((p - 1)/n) a[p - 1], 
        b[p] == 1 + (p/n) b[p - 1], 
        a[1] == 1 + 2/n, 
        b[0] == 1}, 
     {a[p], b[p]}, p]
```

Having done this, I would like to set $p=n-1$ and then plot the resulting functions $a[n-1]$ and $b[n-1]$ for $n=1, ..., 1000$.

I am failing at the first hurdle as *Mathematica* version 8 just returns the RSolve line when I press shift-enter.

**Update.**  Following a request for an example using Maple 16.  I do the following.

```
rsolve({a(1) = 1+2/n, a(p) = 1+(p-1)*a(p-1)/n+2*b(p-1)/n, b(0) = 1, b(p) = 1+p*b(p-1)/n}, {a(p), b(p)});
subs(p = n-1, %);
```

I then copy the result for a(n-1) and plot it

```
plot([seq([n, (1/n)^(n-1)*n*GAMMA(n-1)*(Sum((n+2*(1/n)^p1*exp(n)*GAMMA(p1+1, n))/(n^2*(1/n)^(p1+1)*GAMMA(p1+1)), p1 = 1 .. n-2)+1+2/n)], n = 2 .. 200)], style = point);
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: First issue is the syntax : `RSolve` with capital S.

Comment: Strongly related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16919/193

Comment: Sorry... copy and paste error. I have the same problem with RSolve with a capital S. Is there a way to restart so that there are no existing function/variable settings or is there some other reason it doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: solving for `b[p]` seperately produces a solution for `b` : `solb = RSolve[{b[p] == 1 + (p/n)*b[p - 1], b[0] == 1}, b, p][[1, 1]]`. Substituting this in the other equation seems to be more complicated though `sola = RSolve[{a[p] == 1 + (2/n)*b[p - 1] + ((p - 1)/n)*a[p - 1], 
    a[1] == 1 + 2/n} /. solb, a, p]`

Answer (score 5):

In two steps, since they can be decoupled:

```
h1 = RSolve[{
   b[p] == 1 + (p/n) b[p - 1],
   b[0] == 1}, {b[p]}, p]
h2 = RSolve[{
   a[p] == Evaluate[b[p] /. h1[[1]]] + ((p - 1)/n) a[p - 1],
   a[1] == 1 + 2/n}, {a[p]}, p]

DiscretePlot[{b[i] /. Evaluate[h1 /. p -> n - 1 /. n -> i + 1], Sqrt[i]}, {i, 300}]
DiscretePlot[ a[i] /. Evaluate[h2 /. p -> n - 1 /. n -> i + 1], {i, 300}]
```

Comparing `b[i]`with `Sqrt[i]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is `a[i]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

BTW, answering your comment

> Thanks. How can I now do the substitution and plotting? If there isn't a bug then it should look like $sqrt(n)$

here is a reasonable approximation to `b[i]` using `Sqrt[]`:

```
y[i_] := Sqrt@(1.78081659706051 + 1.57076044099885*i) - 0.332147990949542; 
DiscretePlot[Evaluate[b[p] /. h1[[1]] /. p -> n - 1 /. n -> i + 1] - y[i], {i,10000}, 
             PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, if you want an exact result:

```
b[n] -> E^n n ExpIntegralE[1 - n, n]
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I now do the substitution and plotting?  If there isn't a bug then it should look like $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thanks but isn't it possible to use the answer to RSolve[{
  a[p] == Evaluate[b[p] /. h[[1]]] + ((p - 1)/n) a[p - 1],
  a[1] == 1 + 2/n}, {a[p]}, p] without having to retype the answer for a[n]?

Comment: @lip1 Look at it now

Comment: @belisarius Don't you think _Mathematica_ should be able to solve it the way you did ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks `RSolve[]` functionality is still cutting its teeth

Comment: @belisarius Are you sure the plot of a[n-1] is correct? Here is what I do in Maple and I get a different graph.rsolve({a(1) = 1+2/n, a(p) = 1+(p-1)*a(p-1)/n+2*b(p-1)/n, b(0) = 1, b(p) = 1+p*b(p-1)/n}, {a(p), b(p)});

subs(p = n-1, %);

I then copy the answer for a(n-1) and do  plot([seq([n, (1/n)^(n-1)*n*GAMMA(n-1)*(Sum((n+2*(1/n)^p1*exp(n)*GAMMA(p1+1, n))/(n^2*(1/n)^(p1+1)*GAMMA(p1+1)), p1 = 1 .. n-2)+1+2/n)], n = 2 .. 200)], style = point)

Comment: @belisarius In fact it should look like $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} n}$ in the limit.

Comment: @lip1 b[n] behaves like Sqrt[Pi/2 n] when n->Infinity, yes

Comment: @lip1 Please post an image, I haven't Maple available here now.

Comment: @lip1 I cross checked the plot for a[i] and seems right

Comment: @belisarius I mean a[n-1] behaves like $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} n}$.

Comment: Are you completely sure? because it's b[n] the one that behaves EXACTLY like that

Comment: @belisarius See update.

Comment: @belisarius I got downvoted for posting the picture!

Comment: @lip1 No, you haven't got downvoted. I removed my upvote until you put some more work on your question. You have now two expressions that pretend to solve your problem. I suggest replacing that expressions back into the original equations and see if both of them comply.